# Django FORM_RENDERER for frontend only

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin, django-settings

By default Django uses this setting determine where the form widgets come from:

```
FORM_RENDERER = 'django.forms.renderers.DjangoTemplates'
```

As we want all labels removed, and apply some overrides, it was changed to:

```
FORM_RENDERER = 'django.forms.renderers.TemplatesSetting'
```

This all works fine for the frontend.  However, it renders the backend unusable as now all labels are removed there as well.

My question, how do I get Django to use the original setting for the admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you cannot split up the frontend and backend.  In the end, I ended up creating custom form/widget classes which I'm using all over the frontend.

The steps were:

1. Keep an original copy of the Django forms in your templates folder
2. Create a duplicate of each widget template you need in your own template folder
3. Create a custom form class which overrides the template_name in **init** to force the use of your custom templates.  This formclass can be treated as a mixing.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this might help, but you might want to look into adding the django templates dir to your TEMPLATES in settings:

```
import django

INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
'django.forms',
...]

FORM_RENDERER = 'django.forms.renderers.TemplatesSetting'
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(APPS_DIR, "templates")  # ROOT dir for templates
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR, django.__path__[0] + '/forms/templates'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

This enables me to have my own template in my ModelForm like so:

```
class DealerDepartmentFrom(forms.ModelForm):
    error_css_class = "is-invalid"
    template_name = "form_templates/custom_form_template.html"
```

The reason for me going down this rabbit hole was to get a way to add the error_css_class to the  element.